# What was the first Version of Opera Mini browser and Is there any emulator for that version?

Tags: browser, opera, emulation

What was the first Version of **Opera Mini** browser and Is there any emulator for that version?

I'm on Windows 7 and I want to test a website with Oldest Opera Mini.

Answer (score 1):

the latest available version i could find is 3:

- http://www.opera.com/mobile/download/versions/

which, according to [this site](http://my.opera.com/opera.mini/archive/) is from november 2006. i am not aware of any emulator for that, but http://www.opera.com/mobile/demo/ seems to use http://www.microemu.org/:

```
MicroEmulator is a pure Java implementation of Java ME in Java SE.
```

i tried the mini3 and it seemed to work, so good luck with your own research:

[image]

you can test version 4 of the opera mini browser [directly at opera](http://www.opera.com/mobile/demo/?ver=4).